# Unable to render the data received via BehaviourSubject

Tags: angular

I tried receiving data using BehaviourSubject in compoennt.ts file and after console logging it i see the desired results but when i tried to render it in html component i failed 
Below is the code for that

compoennt.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/shared/product.service';


@Component({
selector: 'app-updatecardproducts',
templateUrl: './updatecardproducts.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./updatecardproducts.component.scss']
})
export class UpdatecardproductsComponent implements OnInit {
subscription:Subscription
carddetails
constructor(private prservice:Productservice) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.subscription=this.prservice.updatedproduct.subscribe(
  (res:any)=>{
console.log(res)
  }
)

}

}
```

html component

```
 <mdb-card>
 <div class="view rgba-white-slight waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
<mdb-card-img src="{{res?.imageurl}}" alt="Card image cap"></mdb- 
card-img>
<a>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</a>
</div>
<mdb-card-body>
<mdb-card-title>
  <h4>{{res?.title}}</h4>
</mdb-card-title>

<mdb-card-text> {{res?.price}}
</mdb-card-text>

</mdb-card-body>
</mdb-card>
```

Here is ss of what i received in the console

https://ibb.co/b3s7P7x

Comment: You have to assing the result from the subscription to a variable. In your case, declare a variable `res:any`; and in the subscription do: `this.res = res.Items;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign res to public variable then use it in html.

```
export class UpdatecardproductsComponent implements OnInit {

res: any = {};

subscription:Subscription
carddetails
constructor(private prservice:Productservice) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.subscription=this.prservice.updatedproduct.subscribe(
  (res:any)=>{
    this.res = res;
    console.log(res);
  }
)
```